# What is growth of $\psi_q(m) = \min \{ p: m ∣ (q^p−1) \}$ for fixed $q$?

Tags: asymptotics, number-theory

I have to estimate the computational complexity of some algorithm that does $\psi_q(m)$ iterations. Assume that all inputs $m$ are coprime to $q$.

So I need to know what growth the $\psi(m)$ has.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this should be considered on-topic for Computer Science.StackExchange?  What's the relationship/relevance to computer science?  Would you care to share with us the context where you ran into this?  Without further motivation it sounds like it might be question that's better suited for MathOverflow, but it's hard to judge without knowing more, so I hope you can fill us in!  See http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/704/755 for extended discussion.

Comment: @D.W. I have opened the algorithmic context that raises this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the context, Piotr.  I'm still not sure about the choice of sites (I still suspect you'd be more likely to get good answers on MathOverflow, as the question itself has no CS content), but I'll leave it to others to determine whether this is suitable for CS.SE.

Comment: @D.W. Yes, you are quite right with $\psi_q(m) = \min \{ p:~ m ~∣~ (q^p−1) \}$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line: I expect the answer to be $\psi_q(m) = O(m)$, and this to be approximately tight: I don't expect you to be able to prove any significantly better upper bound on $\psi_q(m)$.

Basically, $\psi_q(m)$ is the order of $q$ in the multiplicative group of integers modulo $m$, i.e., in $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$.  In other words, it is the smallest natural number $p$ such that $q^p \equiv 1 \pmod m$.

The structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$ is well-characterized: for instance, when $m$ is prime, it is cyclic of order $m-1$.  As a consequence, $\varphi(m-1)$ of the elements of this group will have order $m-1$ (where $\varphi(\cdot)$ denotes Euler's totient function).  It's known that the typical value of Euler's totient function $\varphi(r)$ for a random value of $r$ near $N$ is about $6N/\pi^2$, i.e., $\Theta(N)$; so heuristically we can expect that the typical value of $\varphi(m-1)$ will be $\Theta(m)$ (roughly some constant times $m$).  See, e.g., [this summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_of_the_function).

In particular, when $m$ is a random prime, close to half of all elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$ have order $m-1$: or to say this in a more careful way, we should expect that a constant fraction of group elements will have order $m-1$.  This means that, for a randomly chosen element of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$, the average order will be $\Theta(m)$.  Of course, $q$ is not a random element -- it is a fixed number -- but as $m$ gets large, we can heuristically treat $q$ as a  random element of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$.

Moreover, the primes are relatively dense among all the integers.  (And even for a random composite, I think the same is still true: a randomly chosen element of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$ will have expected order $\Theta(m)$.)

Therefore, heuristically, I think $\psi_q(m) = O(m)$ is about the best bound you're going to be able to get.  This entire argument is based upon heuristics and is not something I can prove formally, but I think it should give an estimate that's good enough for evaluating the running time of your algorithm.

Comment: You confirmed my wild guess. The average complexity of algorithm works for me. Thank you very much!